# Cannot get my services to be discovered using bluetoothctl

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have a strange issue using Bluez 5.66 on a raspberry PI.
I'm trying to connect a device with mac address "53:4E:48:00:00:0C" and then discover services and caracteristics. The service on the device is not advertized so I need to connect to the device to see it. But upon connection, no services are discovered. They should be as they can be seen on windows BLE or nRF connect app.

Here some logs of the manipulations I have done, as you can see, there is no logs about services or caracteristics being discovered:

```
root@iot-gate-imx8:/home/compulab/GatewayMHS# bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.66
root@iot-gate-imx8:/home/compulab/GatewayMHS# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller AC:12:03:9A:F4:9C Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller AC:12:03:9A:F4:9C Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C 53-4E-48-00-00-0C
[NEW] Device 90:FD:9F:A7:EE:EF Expl_11
[NEW] Device 68:02:5C:2C:9A:95 68-02-5C-2C-9A-95
[bluetooth]# scan off
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Device 68:02:5C:2C:9A:95 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device 68:02:5C:2C:9A:95 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 90:FD:9F:A7:EE:EF RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller AC:12:03:9A:F4:9C Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# connect 53:4E:48:00:00:0C
Attempting to connect to 53:4E:48:00:00:0C
[CHG] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C ServicesResolved: yes
[53-4E-48-00-00-0C]# menu gatt
Menu gatt:
Available commands:
-------------------
list-attributes [dev/local]                       List attributes
select-attribute <attribute/UUID>                 Select attribute
attribute-info [attribute/UUID]                   Select attribute
read [offset]                                     Read attribute value
write <data=xx xx ...> [offset] [type]            Write attribute value
acquire-write                                     Acquire Write file descriptor
release-write                                     Release Write file descriptor
acquire-notify                                    Acquire Notify file descriptor
release-notify                                    Release Notify file descriptor
notify <on/off>                                   Notify attribute value
clone [dev/attribute/UUID]                        Clone a device or attribute
register-application [UUID ...]                   Register profile to connect
unregister-application                            Unregister profile
register-service <UUID> [handle]                  Register application service.
unregister-service <UUID/object>                  Unregister application service
register-includes <UUID> [handle]                 Register as Included service in.
unregister-includes <Service-UUID><Inc-UUID>      Unregister Included service.
register-characteristic <UUID> <Flags=read,write,notify...> [handle] Register application characteristic
unregister-characteristic <UUID/object>           Unregister application characteristic
register-descriptor <UUID> <Flags=read,write...> [handle] Register application descriptor
unregister-descriptor <UUID/object>               Unregister application descriptor
back                                              Return to main menu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
export                                            Print environment variables
[53-4E-48-00-00-0C]# list-attributes
[53-4E-48-00-00-0C]# back
Menu main:
Available commands:
-------------------
advertise                                         Advertise Options Submenu
monitor                                           Advertisement Monitor Options Submenu
scan                                              Scan Options Submenu
gatt                                              Generic Attribute Submenu
admin                                             Admin Policy Submenu
player                                            Media Player Submenu
endpoint                                          Media Endpoint Submenu
transport                                         Media Transport Submenu
list                                              List available controllers
show [ctrl]                                       Controller information
select <ctrl>                                     Select default controller
devices [Paired/Bonded/Trusted/Connected]         List available devices, with an optional property as the filter
system-alias <name>                               Set controller alias
reset-alias                                       Reset controller alias
power <on/off>                                    Set controller power
pairable <on/off>                                 Set controller pairable mode
discoverable <on/off>                             Set controller discoverable mode
discoverable-timeout [value]                      Set discoverable timeout
agent <on/off/capability>                         Enable/disable agent with given capability
default-agent                                     Set agent as the default one
advertise <on/off/type>                           Enable/disable advertising with given type
set-alias <alias>                                 Set device alias
scan <on/off/bredr/le>                            Scan for devices
info [dev]                                        Device information
pair [dev]                                        Pair with device
cancel-pairing [dev]                              Cancel pairing with device
trust [dev]                                       Trust device
untrust [dev]                                     Untrust device
block [dev]                                       Block device
unblock [dev]                                     Unblock device
remove <dev>                                      Remove device
connect <dev>                                     Connect device
disconnect [dev]                                  Disconnect device
menu <name>                                       Select submenu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
export                                            Print environment variables
[DEL] Device 90:FD:9F:A7
```

Here the BTMON logs associated:
https://pastebin.com/0pk7g5Qi

I also tried with bluepy library with this code:

```
from bluepy import btle
btle_peripheral = btle.Peripheral(self.mac_address, "random")
btle_peripheral.setMTU(247)
info(btle_peripheral.getServiceByUUID(UUIDs.service_uuid.value))
info(f"Service with uuid {UUIDs.service_uuid.value} obtained for implant {self.mac_address}")
del btle_peripheral
```

And no problem, the service is discovered just fine:

```
""2023-03-10 12:26:17" root test_discover_peripheral_bluepy 155 [INFO]: Service <uuid=6d796865-6172-7473-656e-74696e656c20 handleStart=10 handleEnd=23>"
""2023-03-10 12:26:17" root test_discover_peripheral_bluepy 156 [INFO]: Service with uuid 6d79686561727473656e74696e656c20 obtained for device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C"
```

Here the BTMON logs associated:
https://pastebin.com/CAzvrnxP

As you can see in this picture, the service is shown without any issues:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvs4n.png

Do you know any way to troubleshoot this issue ? I've tried then "menu gatt" and "list-attributes" while being connected, but nothing was shown, is there a command to see the services and caracteristics discovered on a connected device ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Yes ! The device I use has an auto disconnect after 30 seconds of inactivity : the importants logs are these one:
[CHG] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 53:4E:48:00:00:0C ServicesResolved: yes
So just after the connection, nothing is discovered. I will try btmon thanks !

Comment: I added the BTMON logs in my question, I'm not a specialist of BLE protocol at this level so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Strange error, the RPi is the version 4 so it should support BLE 5.0. And before I've used a bluetooth library "bluepy" that seemed to work well regarding discovering services. I will try with another raspberry to see if it's a configuration issue.

Comment: I just added the bluepy version and its logs that work fine.